# How to minimize the .rst file size of a transient structural analysis in Ansys APDL?

Tags: transient, ansys-apdl

I am running a transient structural analysis for a 600 secs time durarion, with a time step 0.1. The problem is that the .rst file is exceeding 1TB in size. From the expected results, I only need the displacement of a specific node and the von Mises stress in 2 elements of interest.

Due to the specifications of the analysis, I need to keep the time and timestep unchanged.

I have already employed the OUTRES command to minimize the file size. However, when I use the CM command to specify the elements of interest, at the end of the analysis, only the result of the last substep is obtained, even though I have configured the OUTRES command to record all results.

I would appreciate if someone could provide me with an approach to reduce the .rst file while ensuring that I have the result for all substeps.